# Mapbox Choropleth map not working properly

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I try to make a chroropleth map with mapbox gl js. It kind of works with the code below, but it's also a bit "buggy". When i hover over the map the popup is only sometimes there.

Is there a way to show the popup only in the middle of each feature?

I am new to mapbox and javascript and this is my first help request here, so apologies for any inconveniences.

```
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'xxx';
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'xxx',
         center: [8.798, 53.122],
        zoom: 8.15
    });

  map.on('load', () => {
        map.addSource('members', {
            type: 'vector',
            url: 'xxx'
        });

 map.addLayer({
            'id': 'members_1',
            'type': 'fill',
            'source': 'members',
            'source-layer': 'final_mitgliederV1_1-bcbjyn',
            'paint': {
               'fill-opacity': 0
            }
           },       
             );

        // Create a popup, but don't add it to the map yet.
        const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
            closeButton: false,
            closeOnClick: false
        });

        map.on('mouseenter', 'members_1', (e) => {
            // Change the cursor style as a UI indicator.
            map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';

            // Copy coordinates array.
            const coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
            const description = e.features[0].properties.m_Mitglieder;

var members = e.features[0].properties.m_members;
          
          var description2 = "" +
                "<div id='header'>" +
              "<div class='tooltip'>" + members + "</div>" + "Mitglieder: ";
            // Ensure that if the map is zoomed out such that multiple

            

            // Populate the popup and set its coordinates
            // based on the feature found.
           popup.setLngLat(e.lngLat).setHTML(description2).addTo(map);
});

map.on('mouseleave', 'members_1', () => {
map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
popup.remove();
});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake: it has to be 'mousemove' instead of 'mouseenter'